# How to predict values by using a model developed by linear mixed modelling with nesting effect?

Tags: r, modeling, prediction, mixed-models, lmer

I have a model developed by using 5 variables in R. Linear mixed modelling method is selected to develop a model with nesting effect.

My R code for the model development is below:

```
model1 <- lmer(Reduction.factor ~ (1|PAI:Open.wind) + 
     (1|PAI:Temp) + (1|PAI:Height)+ (1|PAI:Density)+ PAI  ,
    data = model)
```

4 parameters are nested by PAI.

To see how the model predict in different conditions, I have created different numbers for 5 parameters as a data frame (called "case study").

It looks like this:

```
Temp    Height  Density PAI Open wind
20.000  0.041   0.033   1.960   30.000
20.000  0.082   0.061   1.960   30.000
20.000  0.122   0.059   1.960   30.000
20.000  0.163   0.061   1.960   30.000
20.000  0.204   0.043   1.960   30.000
20.000  0.245   0.048   1.960   30.000
20.000  0.286   0.052   1.960   30.000
40.000  0.082   0.061   1.960   40.000
40.000  0.122   0.059   1.960   40.000
40.000  0.163   0.061   1.960   40.000
40.000  0.204   0.043   1.960   40.000
40.000  0.245   0.048   1.960   40.000
40.000  0.286   0.052   1.960   40.000
```

I wanted to predict 'Reduction.factor' by using those values of 5 parameters.

So I put `p1 <- predict(model1,case study)` to see the predictions.. but only Error in (function (x, n)  : new levels detected in newdata <- this message came up..

How can I predict 'Reduction.factor' by using those values for 5 parameters? And.. If I want to have confidence interval (95%), should I put 'interval='confidence''?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this doesn't look initially like it makes very much sense.  While you *can* use numeric values as grouping variables, it seems that you are more likely to want a simple linear model with interactions, i.e. `lm(Reduction.factor ~ PAI*(1+Open.wind+Temp+Height+Density))` ... ???

Comment: @BenBolker the 4 parameters (Open.wind, Temp, Height, Density) responds differently when PAI is different. PAI is a representation of overall vegetation parameter. When vegetation type changes, the parameters have different rates of increase or decrease. I tried linear modelling, Gamm etc but all showed 70% R2 value, while nesting method gives 90% R2.. That is why I am using it. Does it make sense now? As I am still not goot at statistics and R, please let me know if I am wrong..

Comment: is PAI a continuous variable?  How did you compute your R^2 value?  Improving R^2 isn't the only criterion -- you can trivially increase R^2 up to 100% by including a parameter for every observation. Based on your description, the model I gave above seems about right -- and your model specification looks wrong. Typically you should only use mixed models when you have groups (e.g. experimental blocks) in your experimental design.

Comment: @BenBolker I think PAI is a continuous variable. PAI usually ranges from 0 ~ 5. Any numbers between 0 and 5 are possible depending on local vegetation structure. R2 was calculated by R2 <- 1 - (sum((measured-fitted)^2)/sum((measured-mean(measured))^2)).

Comment: Then I definitely don't think your statistical model makes sense.  Sorry.  Voting to migrate to CrossValidated ...